# Strange behaviour in CSS3 transition with linear gradient

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, linear-gradients

I am trying to make a progress bar and using css3 transition to give it a fill effect.

jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/saurabhsharma/rwLf95c8/)

When I give it a fixed size, it works as usual, but Problem is when I set the `background-size:100%` the fill becomes stretch.

How can I create fill effect using `background-size:100%`?

Progressbar1 is with fixed `width` and `background-size`

Progressbar2 is with 100% `width` and `background-size`

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* PROGRESS */
.progress {
  background-color: #e5e9eb;
  height: 0.25em;
  position: relative;
  width: 24em;
}
.progress-bar {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: width;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #000 50px, #fff 100px, transparent 150px);
  background-size: 24em 0.25em;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width:100%
}

.progress2 {
  background-color: #e5e9eb;
  height: 0.25em;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.progress-bar2 {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: width;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #000 50px, #fff 100px, transparent 150px);
  background-size: 100% 0.25em;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width:100%
}

/* ANIMATIONS */
@keyframes width {
  0%, 100% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.65, 0.85);
  }
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar">
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progress2">
    <div class="progress-bar2">
    </div>
</div>
```